# How to do sorting inside a python dictionary from a predefined list

Tags: python, django, list, dictionary

Hi I have the following dictionary

```
{u'Item1': {'sizes': [u'TT', u'Al', u'TB'], 'jobs': OrderedDict([(u'TT', [{'assign': u'Basi', 'size': u'TTAZ_FI', 'state__name': u'pending', 'id': 1717L, 'item_type': u'Item1'}]),  (u'Al', [{'assign': u'Item1', 'size': u'All', 'state__name': u'success', 'id': 1714L, 'item_type': u'Item1'}]), ...
```

I have a list `A = [RQ, TT, SA, PD, Al, ..]`

I was trying to arrange the jobs based on this list, which is a key inside OrderedDict (OrderedDict([(u'TT'). Is there anyway I can rearrange the OrderedDict with my list mentioned above? So that the first key will be RQ and its corresponding list like that? Any idea guys? Thanks in advance

*********************************** EDITED *************************************

dict = {key: list(d for d in grp) for key, grp in itertools.groupby(data, key=lambda d: d['item_type'])}  # The d['item_type'] will be the key

data is a Django querylist
My list:

```
A = ['FF', 'RO', 'FP', 'OX', 'NP', 'BF', 'IJ', 'IN', 'RB', 'PC', 'CT' , 'PH', 'HP', 'LW', 'BH', 'HJ', 'HN', 'XW', 'GN', 'GP', 'TJ', 'RG', 'BN', 'BP', 'PP', 'IBP', 'EG', 'PG', 'TT', 'TB', 'RM']
```

Comment: `d['Item1']['jobs'] = OrderedDict((key, d['Item1']['jobs'][key]) for key in A)`

Comment: @falstryu: My dictionary `dict = {key: list(d for d in grp) for key, grp in itertools.groupby(data, key=lambda d: d['item1'])}` d is from this dictionary. As per your answer I get an error under 'd'

Comment: And the key is not actually `Item1`. It will be for example 'TT` inside my OrderedDict

Comment: You can iterate the dictionary, and replace `Item1` with key which is being iterated.

Comment: Get an error falstru `list indices must be integers, not str`

Comment: https://ideone.com/b7hKPb

Comment: That cool falstru. But am getting a `key error`. The reason might be because the `jobs` don't have a value which is in the list. How can I resolve that?

Comment: Means there must be a if condition before the for loop may be, just check whether the key is in the list or not

Comment: Could you provide complete key, values for the dictionary?

Comment: `d['Item1']['jobs'] = OrderedDict((key, d['Item1']['jobs'][key]) for key in A if key in d['Item1']['jobs'])`

Comment: @Falstru: All the keys will be definitely inside the list, but all the values inside the list may not be in the dict

Comment: Yeah, I tried that Falstru, got an error like `list indices must be integers, not str`

Comment: edited my question please go through

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the following variables

```
A = ['FF', 'RO', 'FP', 'OX', ...]
jobs = OrderedDict([
    (u'TT', [{...}]),
    (u'FF', [{...}]),
])
```

You can build a key function to sort your OrderedDict

```
key = lambda job: A.index(job[0])
jobs = OrderedDict(sorted(jobs.items(), key=key))
```

The code `A.index(job[0])` returns the index of the job, which is used as the key to order your jobs.

**Edit**

At this point it's probably worth writing a named function for `key`

```
# this will be the index value of codes not in the list "A"
end_index = len(A)+1

def key(job):
    code = job[0]
    if code in A: 
        return A.index(code)
    return end_index

jobs = OrderedDict(sorted(jobs.items(), key=key))
```

Comment: Good idea Derek, but got an error as `list indices must be integers, not unicode`

Comment: Ah my bad! I've updated the answer, you should use `A.index(job[0])` instead, which will return the index of the job from the list `A`.

Comment: Yes!! Thanks Derek. now the problem solved. But still the problem i faced before comes in `u'Al' is not in list` means `Al` is not in the list but its a key in the dictionary. For these kind of values in list, I just want to add them at the end of the dictionary. How can I do that?

Comment: I've updated the answer, which will handle situations where your job codes aren't in the list `A`.

Comment: But Derek, in the case `Al` its not added at the back of the dictionary

Comment: Also there are cases where FP comes first before FN

Comment: @vellattukudy I'm not quite understanding your comment. The answer provided sorts the items in the dictionary, it doesn't add or remove anything. Jobs not in `A` - e.g. `Al` will be at the end of the OrderedDict. The items are sorted exactly to the order in `A`.